# Modify asp.net grid via linq datasource

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

Greeting,
I'm using a grid which gets it's source from a linq expression.

Here is the linq for example :

```
var data = from row in tempCity.AsEnumerable()
           group row by row.Field<string>("City") into city
           select new
           {
              City = city.Key, 
              Count = city.Count()
           };
```

After assigning "data" to the grid's datasource , I get the result I needed.
The problem accrued when I tried to make my application a multi-language friendly, and I can't find a way to translate the City and Count header of my Grid to another language.

I tried to do the followings:
1.Instead of city, write GetLocalResource("City") inside the linq expression instead of the term "City", it didn't work.

2.Change the grid's properties Programically, however, since the linq expression is different for each action , depends on my clients desired, I have no premade columns at my aspx page so I can't reach the grid.Column property- always marked as 0.

3.put all the data of the linq inside a DataTable, I know this one should work, but it doesn't feel right to do it, it seems a bit clumsy and I'd like a cleaner solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose solution 1 would be your favorite. But your LINQ query gets translated into an SQL-query and there is of course no SQL method like GetLocalResource.

Apparently your database stores only city codes and the culture dependent names are in the resources.
I would try the following: use your existing LINQ statement to grab the data. Convert the city to a localized string within your view, e.g.

```
<asp:Literal Text='<%# GetLocalResource(Eval("City"))' runat="server" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, However I don't think it would fit my case as there are two fields at the Linq now, and I have a switch case with scenarios where I have 6 and 9 headers.

Comment: Do you mean you have a different amount of cities depending on localization? Can you clarify your question? Maybe we can come up with a better solution. I just tried to improve your first solution. BTW: It looks like you query an ADO.NET DataTable. What is your DataSource?

Comment: Indeed I'm taking some result from a DataTable,the reason I don't think an asp:literal\label\localization will work is due to the fact that depending on my clients queries I will get a different amount of columns to each scenario, I.E : Query 1: "from.. where.. select new{2 fields}" ,Query 2: "from..where..select new {5 fields}" ..

Comment: can you show me some more code? I still don't understand what you want to achieve. Do you have different queries for the same asp.net page?

Comment: I decided to manually translate the all the grid's headers to what I needed and display/hide them as I wish.Thanks for all the help!